# Catch Built-in Exception (rather than self defined)

Tags: python, class, exception, namespaces

I want to patch a library to catch the built-in [ConnectionError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ConnectionError) (which inherits from OSError).

So far so good. As it happens, the library has a "self-defined" Exception that is also called ConnectionError:

```
class LibraryError(Exception):
    pass


class ConnectionError(LibraryError):
    pass
```

I guess, if I now tried to catch a `ConnectionError`, doing something like

```
try:
    do_something()
except ConnectionError as e:
    try_to_get_it_right_again()
```

I would only catch the self-defined `ConnectionError`, which inherits from `LibraryError`. (Disclaimer: I have to admit, I haven't tested that myself, as I didn't know how).

How would I get Python to catch the built-in `ConnectionError`?

Comment: About your disclaimer part, its about scope resolution, so you are right as the built-ins are checked last. Take a look at this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/5050917) if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) module, the explicit name for the namespace where built-in names like `int` and `ConnectionError` live.

```
import builtins

try:
    ...
except builtins.ConnectionError:
    ...
```

In Python 2, this would be `__builtin__`, although Python 2 doesn't have `ConnectionError`. Note that `__builtins__` is its own weird thing; even if it looks like what you want, it's not.

---

If you want code that works in both Python 2 and Python 3... well, the exception hierarchy looks pretty different in Python 2, and ConnectionError doesn't even exist, so it's not as simple as deciding whether to use `builtins` or `__builtin__`. The `builtins`/`__builtin__` thing is easy enough to solve, at least.

To import the right module depending on Python version, you can catch the `ImportError` and import the other module:

```
try:
    import builtins
except ImportError:
    import __builtin__ as builtins
```

Pretending for a moment that Python 2 has ConnectionError, you could save a reference to the built-in `ConnectionError` before shadowing the name:

```
_builtin_ConnectionError = ConnectionError

class ConnectionError(LibraryError):
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Another problem is that the original author wrote the library to run in Python2 *and* in Python3 - so I probably couldn't `import builtins` without breaking Python2 support :(

Comment: @speendo: `try: import builtins` `except ImportError: import __builtin__ as builtins`. Catching ImportError is pretty standard when a module might or might not exist. Alternatively, you can save a reference to the builtin `ConnectionError` before shadowing the name: `_builtin_ConnectionError = ConnectionError`.

Comment: oh, the last option would be a great way to deal with it without hacking around too much! Still, I will ask the original author if he would like to rename his ConnectionError, which would improve readability even more :)

Comment: @speendo: Wait, if you need code that works on both Python 2 and Python 3, you're just going to be catching OSError instead of ConnectionError either way, since Python 2 doesn't have ConnectionError.

Comment: in Python 2 I catch [socket.error](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.error) at the moment. Would you recommend catching OSError? It seems too "general" to me.

Comment: @speendo: Actually, catching OSError wouldn't work, since the exception hierarchy changed in more ways than I realized. In Python 2, `socket.error` doesn't even descend from OSError.

Answer (score 2):

Use the the **[`ConnectionError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ConnectionError)** defined along with the other exceptions in the **[`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html)** library:

```
import builtins

try:
    # connection error raised
except builtins.ConnectionError as conerr:
    # handle stuff
```

Comment: Thank you! The comment I made above would of course also fit to your answer

Comment: thank you for your great help! I really appreciate that! I will still accept @user2357112's answer just because it's a bit more extensive. But please keep up your great work!

Comment: @speendo I really do not mind; there's no need to justify your accepting :-)